# Adding a Filter

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I have this code that is grabbing files in a certain directory.  I would like to filter these files by time. I want the file types to be filtered by 20 seconds or less. How can I add this filter to my code? Thank you.

```
using namespace std; 
typedef vector<WIN32_FIND_DATA> tFoundFilesVector; 
std::wstring LastWriteTime;   
int getFileList(const char * filespec, tFoundFilesVector &foundFiles)
{ 
    WIN32_FIND_DATA findData; 
    HANDLE h; 
    int validResult=true; 

    int numFoundFiles = 0; 
    h = FindFirstFile((LPCSTR)filespec, &findData); //ansi 
    if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    return 0; 

    while (validResult) 
    { 
    numFoundFiles++; 
    foundFiles.push_back(findData); 
    validResult = FindNextFile(h, &findData); 
    } 
    return numFoundFiles; 
} 

void showFileAge(tFoundFilesVector &fileList) 
{ 
    unsigned _int64 fileTime, curTime, age; 
    tFoundFilesVector::iterator iter; 
    FILETIME ftNow; 
    CoFileTimeNow(&ftNow); 
    curTime = ((_int64) ftNow.dwHighDateTime << 32) + ftNow.dwLowDateTime; 

    for (iter=fileList.begin(); iter<fileList.end(); iter++) 
    { 
        fileTime = ((_int64)iter->ftLastWriteTime.dwHighDateTime << 32) + iter->ftLastWriteTime.dwLowDateTime; 

        age = curTime - fileTime; 

        wcout << "FILE: '" << iter->cFileName << "', AGE: " << (_int64)age/10000000UL << "  seconds" << endl; 
    } 
} 

int main() 
{ 
   string fileSpec = "*.*"; 
   tFoundFilesVector foundFiles; 
   tFoundFilesVector::iterator iter; 

   int foundCount = 0; 

   getFileList("c:\\Mapper\\*.txt", foundFiles); 
   getFileList("c:\\Mapper\\*.jpg", foundFiles);
     foundCount = foundFiles.size(); 
    if (foundCount) 
    { 
        wcout << "Found "<<foundCount<<" matching files.\n"; 
        showFileAge(foundFiles); 
    } 
    system("pause"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I don't understand.  You've got 99.9% of the code already written.  Are you saying you to want remove all the files older than 20 seconds from your fileList variable?  (Or keep them).  Or do you want to sort the files based on time?

Comment: I just want to return the files with an age of 20 seconds or less. because I will delete them.  If there are no files that are 20 seconds or less then the program exits. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean no research effort!!! How did I get this far, How about some help!

Comment: I wasn't the one that downvoted, I was merely suggesting you had all the pieces of the puzzle in your code.  (Namely, how to enumerate files, and how to get the age of each file).  In any cases, I touched yup your code below.

Comment: 7549180 No Code, 7606098 Map Code, 7612410 Map Code, 7629115 Same Code Different Problem.....I'm sure that being a programmer that one piece of code has many steps, you fix or correct one problem and you move on to the next.  I didn't ask anyone to help write anything. I brought this code to the table and have been evolving it. Besides, whats wrong with asking for help, if you choose not to, you can simply ignore the thread. No need to be nasty about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your go.  I changed the FindFile calls to explicitly use the "A" version (and explicitly use WIN32_FIND_DATAA instead of WIN32_FIND_DATA).  That cast to LPCSTR looked suspicious, but I didn't know if you were compiling with unicode on or off (Visual Studio defaults to Unicde "W" apis by default).

Also, you weren't calling FindClose, and I added that.  Otherwise, I just use GetSystemTime to get the current time, convert it to file time, and then reference file times as 64-bit ints.  "unsigned long long" is the same as unsigned __int64.

```
using namespace std; 
typedef vector<WIN32_FIND_DATAA> tFoundFilesVector; 
std::wstring LastWriteTime; 

unsigned long long FileTimeToULL(const FILETIME& ft)
{
    unsigned long long ull;
    ull = ft.dwLowDateTime | (((unsigned long long)ft.dwHighDateTime) << 32);
    return ull;
}

int getFileList(const char * filespec, tFoundFilesVector &foundFiles, DWORD dwMaxAgeInSeconds)
{ 
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA findData={}; 
    HANDLE h; 
    int validResult=true; 
    int numFoundFiles = 0; 
    unsigned long long now = 0;
    unsigned long long age = 0;

    SYSTEMTIME stnow = {};
    FILETIME ftnow = {};
    ::GetSystemTime(&stnow);
    ::SystemTimeToFileTime(&stnow, &ftnow);
    now = FileTimeToULL(ftnow);

    h = FindFirstFileA(filespec, &findData); //ansi 
    validResult = (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);

    while (validResult) 
    { 
        bool fIsDirectory = !!(findData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY);
        age = FileTimeToULL(findData.ftLastWriteTime);
        if (age > now)
        {
            age = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            age = now - age;
        }

        // age is the diff between "right now" and when the file was last touched (in 100ns units)

        // convert to seconds
        age /= 10000000;

        if ((age <= dwMaxAgeInSeconds) && (!fIsDirectory))
        {
            foundFiles.push_back(findData); 
            numFoundFiles++; 
        }

        validResult = FindNextFileA(h, &findData); 
    } 

    if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        FindClose(h);
    }

    return numFoundFiles; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I didn't think it was you. I can't understand it. If you don't want to help don't. Why did Raymond feel that he had to be rude?

Comment: Using VS 2010 Multi-Byte. Thank you once again!

Comment: I'm kind of with Raymond.  Your code demonstrated that you knew how to both enumerate files and get the age of each file in the enumeration.  So I'm kind of surprised you didn't understand how to answer your own question.  What was it about my answer that you could not derive yourself?

Comment: I'm just learning this, in bits and pieces, I've only been doing this part time for 2 months, catch me a break!!!!!!

Comment: But you didn't answer my question. What is it about my answer that you could not have figured out for yourself?